# Does comparison really take O(1) time? and if not... why do we use comparison sorts?

Tags: sorting, complexity-theory, time-complexity, quicksort, radix-sort

Consider two k-bit numbers (in binary representation):

```
$$A = A_1 A_2 A_3 A_4 ... A_k $$

$$B = B_1 B_2 B_3 B_4 ... B_k $$
```

to compare we scan from left to right looking for an occurrence of a `0` and check opposite number if that digit is also a `0` (for both numbers) noticing that if ever such a case is found then the source of the `0` is less than the source of the `1`. But what if the numbers are:

```
111111111111
111111111110
```

clearly this will require scanning the whole number and if we are told nothing about the numbers ahead of time and simply given them then:

Comparison take `$O(k)$` time.

Therefore when we look at the code for a sorting method such as high-performance quick sort:

```
HPQuicksort(list): T(n)
  check if list is sorted: if so return list
  compute median: O(n) time (or technically: O(nk))

  Create empty list $L_1$, $L_2$, and $L_3$ O(1) time

  Scan through list  O(n)

  if element is less place into $L_1$ O(k)

  if element is more place into $L_2$ O(k)

  if element is equal place into $L_3$ O(k)

  return concatenation of HP sorted $L_1$, $L_3$, $L_2$  2 T(n/2)
```

Thus: `T(n) = O(n) + O(nk) + 2*T(n/2) ---> T(n) = O(nklog(n))`

Which means quicksort is slower than radix sort.

Why do we still use it then?

Comment: I see mathjax doesn't work here. How do you recommend I format?

Comment: Code formatting. It's not as feature-rich as MathJax, since it mostly just monospaces everything, but it's what we have.

Comment: Sorry, what? Comparison is implemented in silicon. It takes one cycle or something. Can you clarify what exactly you're talking about? If you're sorting instances of a BigInt data structure with arbitrary length bits, sure - I think that's a very rare thing to sort. If you're sorting integers (32/64 bits): 1) it's O(1) no matter what because k is capped. 2) It's not even O(n) up to the cap because it's done instantly.

Comment: Sorting two integers requires the invocation of a comparison of their bits. If the integers are not of fixed size it's not a constant time operation.

Comment: And even then it's obvious radix sort is faster than quick sort if the integers are of fixed size.

Comment: Not quite so obvious - you need to consider the constant factor.

Comment: That factor is the size of the integers I think?

Comment: No it's not. The constant factor includes memory management, relative efficiency of various O(1) instructions, cache effects, etc.

Comment: The big draw of comparison sorts is that comparison is general. We can comparison sort all kinds of data types, but radix sort only works on integers or things we can map to integers.

Comment: It depends on the [context of computational complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_of_computational_complexity).

Comment: Your run time analysis looks correct, I agree that it would be `O(k *n * log(n))`. How is this relevant? I could contrive a data type that requires O(n!) time to compare. I could come up with another specialized sorting algorithm that can sort them in O(n) time. But the only time my algorithm would be better would be when sorting that specific thing. 99.99999% of the time an O(n * log(n)) algo will be the best option.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be two independent questions here:

1. Why do we claim that comparisons take time O(1) when analyzing sorting algorithms, when in reality they might not?
2. Why would we use quicksort on large integers instead of radix sort?

For (1), typically, the runtime analysis of sorting algorithms is measured in terms of the number of comparisons made rather than in terms of the total number of operations performed. For example, the famous sorting lower bound gives a lower bound in terms of number of comparisons, and the analyses of quicksort, heapsort, selection sort, etc. all work by counting comparisons. This is useful for a few reasons. First, typically, a sorting algorithm will be implemented by being given an array and some comparison function used to compare them (for example, C's `qsort` or Java's `Arrays.sort`). From the perspective of the sorting algorithm, this is a black box. Therefore, it makes sense to analyze the algorithm by trying to minimize the number of calls to the black box. Second, if we do perform our analyses of sorting algorithms by counting comparisons, it's easy to then determine the overall runtime by multiplying the number of comparisons by the cost of a comparison. For example, you correctly determined that sorting n k-bit integers will take expected time O(kn log n) using quicksort, since you can just multiply the number of comparisons by the cost of a comparison.

For your second question - why would we use quicksort on large integers instead of radix sort? - typically, you would actually use radix sort in this context, not quicksort, for the specific reason that you pointed out. Quicksort is a great sorting algorithm for sorting objects that can be compared to one another and has excellent performance, but radix sort frequently outperforms it on large arrays of large strings or integers.

Hope this helps!